# Battling Java heap size, big difference between Java locally and Java web start

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I had a call of a customer last weekend telling me their Java program was not responding when doing an import of data. The data is a simple Excel workbook with 4 worksheets. All data is being read from the columns and added to a database.

So I started to investigate and had some strange results.

1. **Testing the import by using Run in Netbeans.** This uses Java 64-bit instance:

*First run*

[image: local first run (64-bit)]

*Second run*

[image: local second run (64-bit)]

2. **Testing the import by using Java Web start.** This is being launched by opening a JNLP file and uses a Java 32-bit instance:

*First run*

[image: webstart first run (32-bit)]

In this case I had the same issue which the customer was reporting, the program stopped responding after a while going through the import process. This is caused because I'm reaching the max heap size as far as I can tell (red circle).

*Second run*

So I've decided to increase the initial heap size and max heap size by adding the following to my JNLP file: `initial-heap-size="512m" max-heap-size="1024m"`. When I tested the import again, it seemed to work, however I notice there is much more memory used compared to the first 2 cases:

[image: webstart second run (32-bit)]

- Why is there a 300mb difference in memory usage between case 1 and 2 compared to case 4?
- Is this high memory usage the result of bad programming or a memory leak? Or is it normal to have such high values?
- Is adding `initial-heap-size="512m" max-heap-size="1024m"` a valid solution for this issue?

Comment: @StackFlowed I doubt that very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the obvious differences are that your first runs are done with a `64-bit server VM` and the latter ones are done with a `32-bit client VM`.

Supposedly the client VM is optimized for better usability in a desktop type application, and the server VM is optimized for "server" work. I don't have a full list of the differences (or whether it's really something that works out well in actual use cases). Don't quote me on this, but I do believe that the client VM avoids GC more than the server VM, because it was at least at one point perceived as slow. That would explain why the client VM is using a lot more memory, instead of aggressively releasing it.

Fiddling with the GC parameters is sometimes the correct thing to do, and in this case it's pretty much the only thing you can do, unless you identify any significant memory leaks. It's not a bad idea to be familiar with what makes the GC tick in any case though.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, I checked my application further on memory leaks by looking at Eden & Old gen space but saw nothing spectacular. For now it is fixed with the initial-heap-size and max-heap-size but I'll see if I can optimize my code more. I think the memory peaks are caused by controls being shown/hidden. Allthough I'd guess it should keep the references instead of creating new ones in memory?

Comment: Yes, if you're just hiding a component it doesn't make it eligible for GC. You should run the memory sampler for a while to see if you can identify any other hotspots.

Comment: I changed my code. I did a lot of database requests for creating entities based on user input, always creating a Client object to handle that request. Seems that this was causing the memory issues. I now put all entities to be created into a wrapper and create them in a single request.